# Ash tree gender

Tags: identification

Is there a way to identify the gender of an ash tree before it reaches full maturity and the seed pods begin to form?
I have some 2'-6' trees and would like to know which ones will be male and not make seed pods?
Thanks
Larry

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption you mean Fraxinus sp., you need to wait for flowers to arrive; identification as male is usually confirmed when it fails to produce samaras, or seeds. Guidance on how to tell male from female flowers here http://homeguides.sfgate.com/identify-ash-tree-male-flowers-75506.html but it is not impossible for an Ash tree to produce both male and female flowers on the same tree, just on different branches.